# Gdiplus::Image from screen (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, screenshot, gdi+, gdi

How would I, if possible, set a `Gdiplus::Image` to what's currently being displayed on
an `HDC`/`HWND` (ie, a screenshot)?

I've tried several things, but I won't get it working. Please help! :)

Comment: This video explains ( with actual code) how  to get a screenshot from screen and save as bmp : https://youtu.be/2fmzooBKp8A  You can then convert it to a GDIPlus::Image subsequently .

Comment: Is there someway I can do it without OpenCV?

Comment: Opencv not require. In the link the screenshot is converted to HBITMAP. Then use Bitmap::FromHBITMAP  to convert to a GDI object directly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just get gdiplus graphics context and call DrawImage for your image:

```
HDC dc = ...;
Gdiplus::Image image = ...;
Graphics graphics(dc);
dc.DrawImage(image,x,y);
```

There are many of DrawImage versions in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawimage(image_int_int)); choose the one that fits your needs.